# Is filling a grid with images so I could control location a good practice?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to locate a few images on a grid, but when I try to do something like

```
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.grid(row = a, column = b)
```

where `a,b` are values that should bring the image to the center of the grid, I always get the image on the top left corner, because empty columns/rows don't fill the space. So, using a friend's advice, I added a blank image and did something like

```
a = 0
b = 0

for img in ls2: # ls2 is a list containing instances of the blank image
    a += 1
    if a == 11:
        a = 1
        b += 1 

    panel = Label(root, image = img)
    panel.grid(row = a, column = b)
```

Now, when I'm trying to locate a new image on `row = x, column = y` it goes as I wanted and this is my current solution. My question is, is this a good way to enable me use the whole grid?

Comment: You've got a good answer already, but I'd like to point out that if you really did need a filler to position things right, you don't need a blank image to do so: a `Frame()` with `width=` and `height=` options specified will do the job, without the memory overhead of a useless image.

Comment: @jasonharper do you mean a frame within a frame? I've tried that with no success :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a good way. There is no need to create invisible widgets. It's hard to say what the good way is, however, because "use the whole grid" is somewhat vague.

If by "use the whole grid" you mean want to create a grid where all rows are the same height, and all of the columns are the same width, and the grid fills its containing window, the right solution is to create uniform rows columns using `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure`.

For example, if you want to create a 4x4 grid of equal sized cells, you could do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

for row in range(4):
    root.grid_rowconfigure(row, uniform="default", weight=1)
for column in range(4):
    root.grid_columnconfigure(column, uniform="default", weight=1)

label_2_2 = tk.Label(root, text="row 2, column 2", borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
label_1_0 = tk.Label(root, text="row1, column 0", borderwidth=2, relief="groove")

label_1_0.grid(row=1, column=0)
label_2_2.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

The `uniform` option takes any arbitrary string. Every row (or column) with the same value will have the same dimensions.

The `weight` option tells grid how to allocate any extra space. By giving each row and each column an identical non-zero weight, all extra space will be apportioned equally, causing the rows and columns to grow or shrink to fit the window.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the **place** geometry manager. It is more explicit and lets me control the exact locations of my images inside the widget.

`panel.place(x=100, y=100)` gives pixel precision location which was what I looked for in the first place.